# Jquery mobile error with localStorage

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I developed a jquery mobile web-app and it works great on pc and on some mobile devices.
Now I tested it on a blackberry z10 and on an ipad mini and the app doesn´t work on this devices.

I build a example app (code below) where I found out, that the reason is the access on the localStorage.

If I delete the line with the set or an line with a get access to the localStorage it works fine.

Error: I can´t change the Page with the localStorage access.
Without the line...

```
localStorage.setItem("test", "testal");
```

...it works.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titel</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/modernizr.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Menü</li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="next()" data-transition="slide">Example</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="runde">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
            <h1>Header 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="application/javascript">
    function next() {
        localStorage.setItem("test", "testal");
        $.mobile.changePage( "#runde", { transition: "slide" });
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a version issue. here is an overview for that:
http://caniuse.com/#index

also on ipad you could try to turning off private browsing...

Comment: It can´t be a version issue because localStorage is compatible with Blackberry 10.